# What is the safest method to bring a perforce client in a clean state?

Tags: perforce

I am new to perforce and trying to understand the following:

I would like to keep a debug client in my workspace. The idea is, before checking in anything in the main code depot, I would like to bring the CL in my debug client and run some qualification or regression to make sure that I'm not breaking anything. So, I want my debug client to always mirror the main code-repo.

Is "p4 sync -f" enough to ensure that- assuming that I don't have any opened (p4 edit/open/add etc) file in my debug client? Will force sync also overwrite the locally edited files (not p4 edit) ?

Answer (score 5):

"p4 sync -f" will force all of the depot files to be downloaded to your client, but it won't remove files from your client that aren't in the depot.  I would recommend using "p4 clean" instead (your server needs to be at version 2014.1 or higher -- if you're on an older server you can script an equivalent but it's a few extra steps).

I.e. do:

```
p4 sync ...
p4 clean ...
```

to make sure you have an up to date clean copy of everything in the current directory.

Comment: Awesome.. thanks Sam. I'll look into that. I'm looking for something similar. I just want to make sure my client is an exact mirror of depot- without any open/edited/newly created local files.

Comment: What is the P4V application equivalent of sync?  ;refresh, get latest, etc?

Comment: "Get Latest" is the same as "sync #head".  In some places P4V uses other words for sync, e.g. I think "sync #none" is "Remove from workspace".  I'm not sure if it has working support for "p4 clean".